# Locating a specific part in a String array using a certain keyword Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Im trying to create a method that will take in a String (name) and go through this array and keep only that specific line. I can not change how this info is stored as a lot of code is based on this arrangement.

Id like to put in "mike" and it remove all the other parts of the array and give me back that single line.

```
private static final String[][] MsgKeys =
            {
                    {"mike", "75", "up"},
                    {"john", "15", "up"},
                    {"eric", null, "left"},
                    {"mark", null, "right"},
                    {"chris", "87", "up"},
                    {"shawn", null, "left"},
                    {"blake", "67", "left"},
                    {"bentley", null, "right"}
        }
```

Comment: You should really consider using a list/array of classes, not a 2d list of strings

Comment: Arrays have a fixed length. So you can not remove elements but only set them to null.

Comment: Also, there is a difference in "locate" and "modify the data structure", which sounds like you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I don't think removing anything is a good idea. Specifically, arrays have a fixed size, so you'd need to either change this to a list, or create a brand new array.

Since you didn't define the behavior of multiple rows with the same name, how about returning just the first matching row, or null if not found?

```
private String[] getRow(String name, String[][] data) {
  for (String[] row : data) {
    if (data[0].equals(name)) return row;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not completly remove Elements out of an Array because it has a fixed length.
What you can do is return a second 1d Array.

```
private String[] getLineByName(String name){
    String[] ret;
    for(int i = 0; i < MsgKeys.length; i++){
        if(MsgKeys[i][0].equals(name)){
            ret = MsgKeys[i];
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you shouldn't remove elements from the `array`, but you can find the row using `stream`:

```
public static String[] findRow(String name, String[]... array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .filter(row -> Objects.equals(row[0], name))
            .findAny().orElse(null);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
String[] row = findRow("mike", MsgKeys);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
```

Output:

```
[mike, 75, up]
```